# Can you display data from a database in a WordPress blog post?

Tags: wordpress

I'm a complete WordPress noob, so forgive any ignorance in the following question.

I have a database with NFL players' statistics and I'm interested in displaying that information in a blog post.  Is it possible to have a SQL call to render that data be made when the user views the post?  In other words, I'm trying to avoid cutting-and-pasting data from the database and into the blog post.  I'd prefer to have a call to the database pull that data out and simply display it in the post.

Any insight into this topic is appreciated.  FWIW, I'm a developer, so feel free to speak in dev-terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve this and more by making a page and using a template for that page.
The template will be a copy of `page.php` (standard single page).

Edit the PHP code in there to reflect your DB call and data grid etc;

More details here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages